# How to access redux-toolkit reducer/action from a class component using react-redux connect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a redux-toolkit store at store.js.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import productCurrency from './stateSlices/productCurrency';

const Store = configureStore({
        reducer: {
            productCurrency: productCurrency,
        },
    })
export default Store;
```

The createslice() function itself is in a different file and looks like this below.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
        value: '$',
}

export const productCurrency = createSlice({
        name: 'productCurrency',
        initialState,
        reducers: {
            setproductCurrency(state, newState) {
                state.value = newState
            },
        },
})
export const { setproductCurrency } = productCurrency.actions;
export default productCurrency.reducer;
```

My issue is that I have a class component NavSection that needs to access the initial state and the reducer action setproductCurrency() to change the state. I am trying to use the react-redux connect() function to accomplish that.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { productCurrency } = state
  return { productCurrency: productCurrency.value }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setproductCurrency: () => dispatch(setproductCurrency()),
    dispatch,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavSection);
```

Now, I am able to access the state by ussing this.props.productCurrency. Yet, if I try to access the setproductCurrency() by ussing this.props.setproductCurrency()... Chrome console gives me an error that "this.props.setproductCurrency() is not a function".

Is there a way of fixing this, or am I trying to do something impossible?

## UPDATE #1

I think I just moved the ball in the right direction. I changed the onClick function to be an arrow function as shown below.

```
onClick={() => this.props.setproductCurrency('A$')}
```

Now, setproductCurrency() is considered a function, but it returns a different error when I click the button...

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, payload}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Why would this function now return an object? It is supposed to change the state and trigger a re-render of the page so that the class component can access the newly changed state.

Comment: Can you show the actual entire class component? The `connect` usage looks _legal_, at least.  That said, your `mapDispatch` can be drastically shortened [by using the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) instead: `const mapDispatch = {setproductCurrency}` .  (Also, frankly I would recommend just trying to change the class component to a function component anyway :)  )

Comment: Here is a link to codeshare.io with the NavSection.js class component body - https://codeshare.io/78L7No . Believe me, I would love nothing more but to use functions and hooks, but I am required to use class components.  Thus, required to learn how to use class components, redux, etc. 

Thank you for your help, @markerikson . 

P.S. 

I did use the object shorthand that is recommended in the documentation, but it did not work. Thus, I thought that maybe I need to use the version with dispatch. There might be something about how toolkit and redux interact that I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, RTK has nothing to do with React-Redux, `connect`, or `mapDispatch` :)

The current error of "Objects are not valid as a React child" is because your reducer is wrong.  A reducer's signature is *not* `(state, newState)`.  It's `(state, action).  So, your line` state.value = newState`is really`state.value = action`, and that's assigning *the entire Redux action object* as a value into the state.  That's definitely not correct conceptually.

Instead, you need `state.value = action.payload`.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue thanks to your feedback @markerikson. 1) I refactored the reducer to have a second argument "action" + changed the body to "state.value = action.payload". 2) I got rid of the mapDispatchToProps by changing the connect function to only have mapStateToProps without mapDispatchToProps. 3) And the onClick function now looks as follows "onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(setproductCurrency('A$'))" 

Now the state changes as needed from "$" to "A$" when I click the button. I guess I still don't understand what was wrong with my mapDispatch, but everything works now.